# Type error Redux-Saga middleware with Typescript

Tags: typescript, middleware, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

I am trying to use redux-saga for side effects. As `createStore` is deprecated, I am trying to use `configureStore` from *@reduxjs/toolkit* (version 2.0.1). I followed different tutorials and found that there are two possibilities:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { rootSaga } from './rootSaga'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
    rootReducer,
    middleware: (gDM) => gDM().concat(logger, sagaMiddleware)
  })

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch

export default store;
```

that gives me this error:

```
Type '(gDM: GetDefaultMiddleware<any>) => Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>, Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>, SagaMiddleware<...>]>' is not assignable to type '(getDefaultMiddleware: GetDefaultMiddleware<any>) => Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>]>'.
  Type 'Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>, Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>, SagaMiddleware<object>]>' is not assignable to type 'Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>]>'.
    Type '[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>, Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>, SagaMiddleware<object>]' is not assignable to type '[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>]'.
      Source has 3 element(s) but target allows only 1
```

(if I remove the logger, the last line becomes *Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1*)

or

```
import { configureStore, Tuple } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { rootSaga } from './rootSaga'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
    rootReducer,
    middleware: () => new Tuple(logger, sagaMiddleware)
  })

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch

export default store;
```

that gives me this error:

```
Type '() => Tuple<[Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>, SagaMiddleware<object>]>' is not assignable to type '(getDefaultMiddleware: GetDefaultMiddleware<any>) => Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>]>'.
  Type 'Tuple<[Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>, SagaMiddleware<object>]>' is not assignable to type 'Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>]>'.
    Type '[Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>, SagaMiddleware<object>]' is not assignable to type '[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>]'.
      Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1.
```

If I remove the logger, the error becomes:

```
Type '() => Tuple<[SagaMiddleware<object>]>' is not assignable to type '(getDefaultMiddleware: GetDefaultMiddleware<any>) => Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>]>'.
  Type 'Tuple<[SagaMiddleware<object>]>' is not assignable to type 'Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>]>'.
    Type '[SagaMiddleware<object>]' is not assignable to type '[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>]'.
      Type 'SagaMiddleware<object>' is not assignable to type 'ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction, undefined>'.
        Types of parameters 'next' and 'next' are incompatible.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
            'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'
```

I am quite new to Typescript, and I am not understanding what is the problem...I searched online, but could not find anything useful.
 Thank you in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3950), looks like it's the same issue with yours.

Looks like there's been a type update since redux toolkit v2, which updates the redux middleware types from v4 to v5, causing middleware packages using v4 middlewares to be not compatible.

I think you'll have to choose between two solutions.

1. decide not to use redux toolkit v2, manually change its version to latest v1(I guess it is `1.9.7`) in pacakage.json & run `npm i`
2. override `redux-logger`, `redux-saga` 's redux version dependency to v5, as described in [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3950#issuecomment-1856573309)

One more thing : I think `rootReducer` must be given as a `reducer` property, and `redux-logger` middleware should be the last middleware

> Note: logger must be the last middleware in chain, otherwise it will log thunk and promise, not actual actions ([ref](https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger?tab=readme-ov-file#usage))

```js
// ...
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (gDM) => gDM().concat(sagaMiddleware, logger)
})
// ...
```